# Prove x < y iff the carry out of MSB is 0

Tags: assembly

Let x and y be numbers in the range [0, 2^n − 1], they each have a valid representation in n-bit unsigned binary. Subtracting y from x is equivalent to adding −y to x, where −y is represented by 2^n − y. Overflow occurs only when x < y.

How can I prove that x < y if and only if the carry out of the most significant bit is 0?

Comment: Did they give you any suggestions for proof techniques or are you supposed to just freestyle it?

Comment: just free style

Comment: think of the carry flag as an external sign bit.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: See also [Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags for signed vs. unsigned](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).  In case anything about unsigned carry from binary subtraction wasn't clear, that will set you straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said `x - y = x + (2^n - y)`. The carry is 0 **iff** the result is less than `2^n`. Thus:

```
x + (2^n - y) < 2^n
x - y < 0
x < y
```